# Find the content of meta tag using regular expression?

Tags: php, regex

I want to get meta tag content using regular expression. 
I am using this expression to do that
`<meta.*property="og:image".*content="(.*)".*\/>`

But in my case the tag name comes like this in some cases

```
<meta.*property="og:image:url".*content="(.*)".*\/>
```

So how can i get the tag content Regardless its comes like first or second tag name?
or how can i get the tag content if property name starts with **og:image**

Comment: Where's the code you've used so far?

Comment: I am using this ```<meta.*property="og:image".*content="(.*)".*\/>``` to get image url from tag but sometimes the meta tag property name comes like this **og:image:url**

Comment: Are you using PHP? If yes, please edit your question to contain a reproducable example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use:

```
^<meta +property="og:image(?::url)?" +content="([^"]+)" *\/>$
```

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DMHKCZ/1/)

1. `^` Matches start of the string or start of line in multiline mode.
2. `<meta` Matches `meta`.
3. `+` matches one or more spaces.
4. `property="og:image` Matches `property="og:image`.
5. `(?::url)?` Optionally followed by `:url`.
6. `"` Matches `"`.
7. `+` matches one or more spaces.
8. `content="` Matches `content="`
9. `([^"]+)` Matches one or more non-quote characters as capture Group 1.
10. `"` Matches `"`.
11. `*` Matches 0 or more space characters.
12. `$` Matches end of string or end of line in multiline mode.

You can also use the `i` flag if `<META ...` is a possibility, for example.

The `^` and `$` anchors aren't really necessary and enforce that the string consists of nothing but a meta tag or if your are processing multiple lines at once and using the multiline flag, `m`, that each tag is on a separate line by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Hi just skip the double quote.

```
<meta.*?property="og:image.*?content="(.*?)".*?\/>
```

or

```
<meta.*?property="og:image.*?".*?content="(.*?)".*?\/>
```

I'd also add a ? just in case you'd get data in a single line.
Something like this:

```
<meta property="og:image:url" content="bbb"/><meta property="og:image" content="aaa"/>
```

in which case without the ? you'd only capture the last content part(aaa), since .* means give me any character and as many as you can. While the .*? means match as many characters as you can but STOP if any of the continual regular expression matches.

Note: If you're scraping websites you could get the entire site in a single line. I for instance use output buffering and replace all the newlines so the output to the browser is an actual one block HTML a regex with .* without ? wouldn't work as expected if there are many string occurrences that would otherwise be matches.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you want to capture the value of *content* attribute,
placed after *property* attribute with value of either
*og:image* or *og:image:url*.

To handle the case of "either *og:image* or *og:image:url*" use
a non-capturing group `(?:...)`, containing *:url*, with `*` after it
(may occur or not).

Another hint is that when you capture the *content* property, use
`[^"]+` instead of `.*`.
Otherwise the capture content will match everything up to the terminating `/>`.

The whole regex

```
<meta.*property="og:image(?::url)*".*content="([^"]+)".*\/>
```

For a working example see https://regex101.com/r/bME0Y8/1